# Using enum to lookup long String description

Tags: java

I am looking for a convenient way to lookup String description based on the provided String, and I was wondering does it make sense to do that using an enum or maybe there is a better pattern in java for something like this. So I came up with somethig like this:

```
public enum Descriptions
{
    A("text text text text text text text text"),
    B("text text text text text text text text"),
    C("text text text text text text text text"),
    D("text text text text text text text text");

    private final String text;

    Strings(final String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }

}
```

Does this make sense ?

Comment: Why not just use constants?

Comment: Well, then the purpose of the class would be to just store constants, I don't really like that, enum structure looks like a better solution but I might be wrong.

Comment: Do you want to get an `enum` when inputting some text or some text from the `enum`?

Comment: *I am looking for a convenient way to lookup String description based on the provided String* sounds like `Map<String,String>`

Comment: *Well, then the purpose of the class would be to just store constants, I don't really like that, enum structure looks like a better solution but I might be wrong.* You are wrong, this is not purpose of enums. You want constants or map.

Besides I don't see a big difference between what you have shown and public static final string A="somestring", etc.

Comment: *Does this make sense ?* IMHO nope.

Comment: *lookup String description based on the provided String* I don't see how you could provide any String using enums. I definitely see how I could do that with a `Map<String, String>` mentioned by Antoniossss, though.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood Your question, from given enum value to return some ENUM instance:

```
public enum DESCRIPTION{    {
    A("This is A"),
    B("This is B"),
    C("This is C"),
    D("This is D");
    SOME_DEFAULT("This is DEFAULT");

    private final String text;

    Strings(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }

    public static DESCRIPTION getDescriptionFromValue(String value){
        for (DESCRIPTION desc : DESCRIPTION.values()) {
            if(desc.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(value)){
                return desc;
            }
        }
        return DESCRIPTION.SOME_DEFAULT;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
DESCRIPTION desc = DESCRIPTION.getDescriptionFromValue("This is A");
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score -1):

If your purpose is just to define string, this is not a good pattern.

You can simply define them as constants

```
public interface Message {
  String A = "Message A";
  String B = "Message B";
}
```

Comment: When using constants, prefer `final class`es, with a `private` constructor. `interface`s don't make sense